# How to dynamically replace ImageView Inside a GridView (Android)?

Tags: java, android, gridview, imageview, fragment

So I need to create a simple board game. It is based on a Gridview (10x10) inside a fragment.The activity also displays another fragment with controls (up down left right). 
I need to move the image inside the GridView when a button on my controls fragment is pressed. So far I managed to populate the GridView but I cannot figure out how to move the images inside.

this is the grid fragment

```
        public class Grid extends Fragment{
        GridView gridView;
        private View rootView;
        public PhotoImageAdapter mAdapter;
        Integer[] image = {
                R.drawable.pucman, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground,
                R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground,
                R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground,
                R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground,
                R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground,
                R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground,
                R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground,
                R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground,
                R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground,
                R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground, R.drawable.ground,
        };


        @Override


        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_grid, container, false);
            gridView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.GridView);
            gridView.setAdapter(new PhotoImageAdapter(this.getActivity(), image));
            return rootView;


        }


    public void goRight()// this function is called by the control fragment.
    {
     // here is my not so fructuous attempt to replace the image in the 
     //second cell with the image of my character

     image[1]=R.drawable.pucman;
     image[0]=R.drawable.ground;

     }
```

this is my Adapter:

```
public class PhotoImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    public Integer[] mThumbIds;



    public PhotoImageAdapter(Context c, Integer[] image) {
        mContext = c;
        mThumbIds = image;


    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(80, 80));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }


        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated ! Thank you :)

Comment: Do you want to make puzzle game?

Comment: Not really, it more a board game with a character that can move across it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally figured it out! I just needed to replace the fragment and commit the transaction when I call `goRight()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to update the adapter in each move, try to add this line after changing the image array with the updated image array:

```
gridView.setAdapter(new PhotoImageAdapter(this.getActivity(), image));
```

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it gives me a " java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.GridView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference".

Comment: how come your grid view is null if you are still in the same window? meybe you have to declare it final

Comment: Eric- your answare to replace the fragment each time is not needed for such a simple action, check your code..